# Optional activity and repeating activity for different actors in an activity diagram

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I've got a game that I'm trying to create an activity diagram for but I run into some problems.

My try so far looks like this:
[image: My try so far]

This shows the flow good, the GUI is created -> Player performs actions one -> Action Two -> Ends turn.

But what I don't really like is how I could solve action 3. It is suppose to be optional and can be performed anytime from the "System creates GUI" action up until "Player ends turn". Though, performing action three still doesn't move the player back or forth in the "main cycle".

The game has 4 players that go through the same cycle but I'm not sure this is a very good way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this using Fork and Join?

[image]

Comment: That's not equivalent to what the OP asked.  In your case #3 runs in parallel to #1 and #2 while the OP has #1->#3 or #1->#2->#3.

Comment: Fork and join is not same as decision and merge node. You need to use decision and merge node for OP sitiuation.